# How to find a timezone depending on the current utc date and an specific hour?

Tags: node.js, typescript, date, timezone, momentjs

How do you find the time zones that match with a current hour, using a pre-saved hour and the current utc day? Lets say I have a cronjob that runs at every hour (UTC), I want to get the current timezones in which it is 10AM every time I run the cronjob, so for example in UTC it might be 9PM but for 'Asia/Cabul' it might be 10AM, next hour it will be 10PM in UTC but maybe it will be 10AM for the timezone 'America/Los_Angeles'. I am using moment.js for this.

Inputs: Current UTC Date, Specific Hour

Output: Timezones matching that specific hour

Comment: Basically you need to loop through the time zones you care about (or all of them) and convert the UTC time to that local time before comparing.  You should try to write this code yourself and ask for help if you get stuck, rather than asking others to write it for you.  Also keep in mind that [Moment has reached end-of-life](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).  Try [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of that approach but I was hoping to find a simpler solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to get the list of timezones there is another moment js library called moment-timezone, which part of the problem was getting that list. After that it gets really easy:

```js
getTimezonesFromDateAndSpecifiHour(findHourAndMinute){
      const now = moment.utc()
      const timezones = moment.tz.names()

      let matchingTimezones
      timezones.forEach((tz)=>{
          const hour = moment.utc(now).tz(tz).format('H')
          if(hour==findHourAndMinute){
              matchingTimezones.push(tz)
          }

      })

      return matchingTimezones

      
  }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're only checking the hour, then you will have mistakes for time zones that are not using whole hour offsets (`:00`) from UTC.  (Many are `:30`  and some are `:45`).